# Stop request processing in CherryPy and return 200 response from a tool

Tags: python, cors, cherrypy

**My Question**

I am looking for a way to stop request processing in a Tool without raising an exception. In other words: I want to stop the request befor it gets to the specified controller and return a 2xx status code?

**Background**

We want our application to support CORS and therefore the preflight request. The idea was to write a tool which hooks `before_handler`. If an OPTIONS request is made, return the relevant CORS-headers and exit.

The problem is, that I havn't found a way to stop the execution flow. This means that the original URL is processed, as it would be if requested normally. The point is: this could lead to security issues, as the preflight request is always made. This is what I have so far:

```
class CORSTool(cherrypy.Tool):
    def __init__(self):
        cherrypy.Tool.__init__(self, 'before_handler', self.insert_cors_header, priority=40)
        cherrypy.request.hooks.attach('before_handler', self.insert_cors_header, priority=40)

    def _setup(self):
        cherrypy.Tool._setup(self)

    def insert_cors_header(self):
        """
        Inserts the relevant CORS-Headers:
        - Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <from-config>
        - Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
        - Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
        """
        if cherrypy.config.get('enable_cors') is True:
            if cherrypy.request.method.upper() == "OPTIONS":
                cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = cherrypy.config.get('cors_domains')
                cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
                cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '86400'

                # Stop execution
                cherrypy.response.body = None
                cherrypy.response.status = 200
                cherrypy.response.finalize()

                # And NOW stop doing anything else...
```

**Alternatives likely not working**

I know that there is a [cherrypy-cors](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cherrypy-cors/1.3) plugin, but from the source I can't see how this stops the execution.

I also know that CherryPy has a MethodDispatcher, but that would mean a complete rewrite of our code.

Searching Stackoverflow I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530817/how-to-stop-request-processing-in-cherrypy) answer, however I don't want to "kill" the execution, I just want a way to prevent the handler from being called.

Comment: see HandlerTool example in cherrypy [wiki](http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/HandlerTool)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just have your Tool set request.handler = None. See [Request.respond](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src/tip/cherrypy/_cprequest.py?at=default#_cprequest.py-668) for the code which implements this and [the CachingTool](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src/tip/cherrypy/_cptools.py?at=default#_cptools.py-408) for an example:

> ```
>     request = cherrypy.serving.request
>     if _caching.get(**kwargs):
>         request.handler = None
> ```